# I wanna pass the value's of my 2 dropdown lists to a query string and pass them to different forms

Tags: asp.net

i have  a form default.aspx in which im having 2 dropdown lists. 
I  have two more forms, daily.aspx and monthly.aspx. I wanna save the selected value of both the dropdown list in the tables of two forms. Each form has its own table. Im using a 3 tier architecture.I mostly wanna do it through query string.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values as

```
Passing Parameters:
Response.Redirect("yourpagename.aspx?key="+DropDown1.Text);

On Receiving page
Getting Parameters:
string key  = Request.QuerString["key"];
  // OR
string key = Request.QueryString.Get("key");
```